# Inventory Turn Ratio

Tags: financial-statements

I was reading the book *Financial Statements* by Thomas R. Ittelson. I had a basic doubt on the calculation of Inventory Turn which is the ratio of COGS (from the Income statement) and inventory (from the balance sheet).

While the income statement reflects the picture in a period and balance sheet at a current point in time, how can we compare the same? Or in other words, COGS will continue to increase as time progresses, but inventory depends on holding capacity and the business type, will not the ratio also be a function of time the business is running?

I am not from an accounting background, so apologies if this is very basic or covered elsewhere. Links to further reading would be helpful too. :)

Comment: The income statement doesn’t reflect the balance sheet.

Comment: "COGS will continue to increase as time progresses" Are you talking about within a reporting period, or long term increases because of inflation? Remember that inventory is the _value_ of inventory, not the number of items, so it is subject to inflation as well.